# Sikuli:java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Cannot call method from the event dispatcher thread

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, webdriver, sikuli

When I try to automate one website application with flex using java web driver and sikuli ,I am getting the error "java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Cannot call method from the event dispatcher thread" after clicking on a button using the following code

```
public static void clickImage(String folder, String file) throws FindFailed {

        Screen screen;
        File loc = new File("images/" + folder + "/" + file + ".png");
        Pattern image = new Pattern(loc.getAbsolutePath());
        screen = new Screen();
        if (isImagePresent(image, 20)) {
            try{
            waitUntilLoadCompletes(folder);    
            screen.click(image,0);//This method is throwing error

            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("click has some prblm"+e);}
        } else {
            new Exception(file+"not found");

        }
```

Also I am getting the following error as well
[error] mouseDown: buttons still pressed - using all
looks like it clicks on the image but it is not releasing the button meaning it press the mouse button but not releasing. Before releasing the button it throws the error I think

I am using sleep in the following fn which is used in above code

```
public static boolean isImagePresent( Pattern img, int time) {
        Screen screen=new Screen();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < time) {
            try {
                System.out.println(screen.exists(img).toString());
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("waiting for image--- "+i+" seconds");
            }
            i++;
            try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wee should not call the method/class from inside the method which is executed because of some event. In my case I was calling the constructor from Buttonactionperformed method

I used one variable and created separate thread and called the constructor .now working

```
  @Override
        public void run() {
           while(true){//System.out.println(start);

           if(start){jButton1.setEnabled(false);

               new Driver(login, jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
              jButton1.setEnabled(true);
               start=false;
           }
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(LoginFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
           }
        }
```